# Updating many-to-many association with REST

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design, http-verbs

I have three different models as `User`, `PermissionSet` and `Permission`. These models represent their SQL tables respectively.

`User` has a many-to-one association `PermissionSet`, a user may have one `PermissionSet` or none. `PermissionSet`s would be owned by none or many `User`s.

`PermissionSet` has many-to-many association with `Permission`s. A `Permission` could be owned by multiple `PermissionSet`s or none, where `PermissionSet`s may own multiple `Permission`s or none at all.

So I created four tables: `users`, `permission_sets`, `permissions` and a junction table, `permission_sets_permissions`.

I need to persist the changes made in a `User`'s `PermissionSet`. This is handled by a model called `PermissionSetGrant`, which has its own table, `permission_set_grants`.

What is the best way to alter the `Permission`s of a `PermissionSet` with a RESTful API, based on HTTP and JSON?

For example, is it a good way to modify a `PermissionSet` with such request:

```
PUT /api/v1/permission_sets/7

//  Payload
{
    "permission_set": {
        //  Assume these properties of the entity aren't changed
        "name": "default",
        "description": "Default permission set.",

        //  Here we're changing the permissions
        "permission_ids": [
            24,
            27,
            35
        ]
    }
}

-> 200 OK
```

or add permissions with an extra REST path instead?

```
POST /api/v1/permission_sets/7/permissions

//  Payload
{
    "permission": 24
}

-> 201 CREATED
```

and when we need to delete that permission

```
DELETE /api/v1/permission_sets/7/permissions/24

-> 203 ACCEPTED
```

I would also add that the request is idempotent and deterministic from the client's aspect. The number of permissions is 100, at least. Hence, batch operations will be performed in second approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is okay I think. If all you want to connect permissions with permissions sets, then you can use multiple ids to describe collections instead of using the payload for the same, e.g.

```
PUT /api/v1/permission_sets/1+2+3/permissions/4+5+6/
DELETE /api/v1/permission_sets/1+2+3/permissions/4+5+6/
```

If I were you I would not stuck by hierarchical URI design, it is inconvenient by most of the time.

```
PUT /api/v1/permissions/4+5+6/into/permission/sets/1+2+3/
DELETE /api/v1/permissions/4+5+6/from/permission/sets/1+2+3/
```

Be aware that there are not REST constraints about URI design, since [REST operates with hyperlinks](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) and machine clients. So from a client perspective it does not matter what structure the URI has as long as it can be described with an URI template. The only thing you have to keep in mind, that there is n:1 relation between URIs and resources, so multiple URIs can identify the same resource, but a single URI cannot identify multiple resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to allow the update of such a large number of permissions at once, then `PATCH` might be your friend:

Looking at the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (which defines the Patch standard), from the client's perspective the API could be called like

```
PATCH /api/v1/permission_sets/7
[
    { "op": "add", "path": "/permission_ids", "value": [ "24", "27", "35" ]}
]
```

However, `PATCH` is not an [idempotent](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) method unfortunately (and neither is `POST`, for pretty much the same obvious reason), so by exclusion you're left with the `PUT`, which is fine, just a bit more verbose than the `PATCH` (the client has to `PUT` the whole object, including the whole collection of permission_ids).